# MacBook Pro suddenly unable to connect to windows shares

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, file-sharing

I have an older MBP running the latest version of Lion. Up until about two or three days ago, I had no problems connecting to my shares on my Windows computer. It is running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

The actual error message is `There was a problem connecting to the server "winmachine".`

I can ping the address of my Windows machine from the MBP, and I have it set with a static IP (192.168.200.45). before I could command-k and type `smb://winmachine` and it would connect straight away. I've also tried replacing `winmachine` with the static IP address, but I get the same result.

Has anyone experienced this sort of issue or read about a fix somewhere? My GoogleFu seems to be weak right now.

Thanks everyone in advanced!

EDIT:

I found this link after some searching: http://fatwalr.us/2011/08/solution-to-my-smb-connection-problem-in-lion/ but of the majority of the command string is blurred so it doesn't do me much good. So far all I have deciphered is `mount -t smbfs < unintelligible > < mac-side share path >`

My first attempt was `mount -t smbfs //winmachine/multimedia /volumes/multimedia`, but that gave an error: `mount: realpath /Volumes/Multimedia: No such file or directory`

EDIT2:

After fiddling with terminal a bit, I got a different error: `mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Cannot allocate memory`. So after a bit more Googling, I came across an apple forum thread that had this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;177078) link. I went into the registry on my windows machine, and the registry keyword the KB article indicated was not present. I put it in there, set its value to 15 (it did not have a default value after being created, as the article stated), and rebooted. Once the windows machine came up, I was still unable to connect to it from my MBP using command+k and `smb://winmachine`. HOWEVER, when I used `smb://192.168.200.45` it was able to connect. Strange things, computers.

I am not going to put this as the answer to my question just yet, since the result I am looking for is to be able to connect to it like before with the machine name. For the time being, however, I am happy that I can connect to the shares again.

Comment: +1 for effort :) Have you tried adding winmachine to /etc/hosts? Like so: `192.168.200.45     winmachine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have no idea really what happened and how the problem resolved itself, but a few days later I had no problems connecting to my windows machine with it's name. I made no changes on either machine (updates, ip address, etc), it just decided to start working. I will update if I find out something concrete.